# Updating states using DeviceEventEmitter vs Context from different screens

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React native app. I want to trigger a function call to a screen from another screen. Should I use DeviceEventEmitter to emit an event and listen to it on another screen, or should I create a state in a Context and add it to the dependency array of useEffect on another screen.

Comment: In most cases, for communication between screens or components in a React Native app, using a Context with useEffect is a better choice.